# Which Linux distribution should I go for learning C/C++/Assembly in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I am a primary windows developer with experience in C#, .NET, Visual C/C++. I want to lean C/C++ development in linux in order to create portable GUI applications which run on both Windows and Linux.

I have used Fedora in past (2005). Want your suggestions to know which is the best distribution currently to learn programming in linux.

Comment: The distro will really not matter as far as learning C/C++ development is concerned. Almost all the tools you will ever need are easily available/installable on every distro.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't really go wrong with any of the major ones.  Personally I use Debian, but Fedora and OpenSUSE are good choices as well.

I would also like to point out that you *can* use C# to create portable GUI applications.  Have a look at [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) and [Gtk#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp).  I have developed quite a few Gtk# apps and they usually run flawlessly on Windows and Linux, with very little work on my part.  It might not be a bad introduction to coding on Linux, as you will be able to use a familiar language.

Answer (score 4):

Any modern Linux distribution will do, as they all includes (or makes it easy to install) GCC. To easily create portable GUI applications, I would recommend taking a look at [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Since every distro worth its salt has a Development Package that includes gcc, g++ and gdb, it's really going to come down to the IDE you develop your code in. Eclipse is an excellent IDE for C & C++ which just happens to be written in java.  So long story short, use whatever distro you are comfortable with, it really doesn't matter all that much.

Comment: He wants to do C/C++/Assembler, I dont think Eclipse is a good choice for that. No need to use 1GB of ram to run eclipse just so you can type some text and compile with nasm, which is the size in less than kb.

Comment: @AntonioP: On what planet does Eclipse use 1Gb of RAM?  the copy running on myt machine right now has 180Mb.  For reference, the running instance of Acrobat Reader is at over 450Mb.  Oh, and he doesn't say he wants to do assembler.

Answer (score 2):

There is none Distribution you couldn't use. If you want an easy distribution working almost out of the box. With a lot of things configured automatically i would suggest you use ubuntu.

If you like to do more things on your own I'd tend to debian. Anyway you could simply code with qt and use the linux box for debugging only.

Answer (score 0):

Slackware, ArchLinux or CentOS.

Stay away from Ubuntu and its derivatives, you will spend more time messing with packet manager apt-get than doing code. If you choose Debian-derivatives you will spend time wondering why your programs dont work only to find out you need packetname-*devel* also (!)

A base Slackware install should be enough to get you started, if you would like to keep having the latest programs, use ArchLinux.

Comment: Can you give me pointers to help me understand what is apt-get , packetname-devel .. etc ? How do slackware get around these limitations ?

Comment: apt-get is the packet manager of debian-derived distributions, it has the largest collection of packets/programs of any other distribution but some of these may some versions behind the main tree. packetname-devel is containing the development libraries for a given program, which means apt-get usualy doesnt install these, for example it doesnt pull in C .h-files so you need to manually install the corresponding -devel packet. Slackware does not have a packet manager but it comes with everything preinstalled, you learn installing stuff yourself if you want. Why the downvote?

Comment: Wow thanks for the downvotes Ubuntuers, without trying to refute.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "to create portable GUI applications which run on both Windows and Linux" - I suggest that you consider Qt (used to be from Trolltech now part of Nokia). http://qt.nokia.com/products/